# How to create or extend a global object

Tags: javascript, object

I'm trying to extend an object from an external JS file that is loaded into a page that may have the same object name present.

I already have an object in the global scope:

```
window.Qo = {}
window.Qo.myvar = 1
```

I need to include a JS file that will extend this if it does exists, or create it if not.

```
  (function(Qo) {
    Qo.prototype.var2 = 2

    function secretFn(value) {
      return value
    }

    Qo.prototype.public = function(value) {
      console.log(value)
      return value
    }
    return Qo
  })(window.Qo = window.Qo || {})
```

The last line, as I understands it, is that the object past to the function is `window.Qo` if it exists, or an empty object if not.

But trying to expend the original object, I get errors that the value is not a function, even if I pass a function to `myvar`.

`TypeError: (intermediate value)(...) is not a function`.

What am I missing here?

Also, is there something else to check when including global object on unknown/untrusted third-party website?

**EDIT**

I made a code based on the answers below:

```
  ;(function(Qo) {
      // Private variable
      var _bar;

      // Private function
      function _atob(value) {
        if(!typeof value === 'undefined')
        return atob(value)
      }
      // Public functions
      Qo.prototype.getBar = function() {
          return _bar;
      };
      Qo.prototype.setBar = function(bar) {
          _bar = bar;
      };

      return Qo;
  })(window.Qo = window.Qo || {})

  Qo.setBar('test')
```

Error: `TypeError: Qo.prototype is undefined; can't access its "getBar" property`

Answer (score 3):

Probably you need to put a semicolon right before the code you posted.
Since

```
whateverPrecedingExpression
(function(Qo) {
    Qo.prototype.var2 = 2

    function secretFn(value) {
      return value
    }

    Qo.prototype.public = function(value) {
      console.log(value)
      return value
    }
    return Qo
  })(window.Qo = window.Qo || {})
```

js will treat `whateverPrecedingExpression` as a function object which you want to call with your following `(...)`

so do sth like

```
whateverPrecedingExpression
;(function(Qo) {
    Qo.prototype.var2 = 2

    function secretFn(value) {
      return value
    }

    Qo.prototype.public = function(value) {
      console.log(value)
      return value
    }
    return Qo
  })(window.Qo = window.Qo || {})
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, check the updated question. I still have an error: `TypeError: Qo.prototype is undefined; can't access its "getBar" property` :/

Answer (score 1):

try below code

```
(function(Qo = window.Qo || {}) {
    Qo.prototype.var2 = 2

    function secretFn(value) {
      return value
    }

    Qo.prototype.public = function(value) {
      console.log(value)
      return value
    }
    return Qo
  })()
```

have a look at this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) on default parameters.

Comment: I've tried this method too (before updating the question) it doesn't work either. `TypeError: Qo.prototype is undefined; can't access its "var2" property`